# Reentrant code confusion

Tags: c++, multithreading, reentrancy

I am trying to understand exactly what re-entrant code means.  I have this code:

```
void HWt::startElement(uint8_t HW, uint8_t val)
{
    writeBitsToregister(REG_VAL + HW*131072, 0, 3, val); //Write bits 0-2
    writeBitToregister(REG_VAL, 3, 1);  //Set bit 3 to 1
    writeBitToregister(REG_VAL, 3, 0); //Set bit 3 to 0
}
```

I must ensure that all the bit writes are atomic.  I was told that this is not re-entrant.  I can understand how to make it thread safe, I can just use a mutex.

How to make it re-entrant safe?  Also, I do not understand what re-entrant means here?  How can the same thread access this function many times?  Can that only happen if this is called within an ISR or recursive?  It is neither of these things.

Comment: Re-entrant means that calling the same function "with its own data" from different threads is safe. I assume REG_VAL is a constant so, calling this function from different threads simultaneously is not safe since you are affecting the same register from mutliple threads. This is not re-entrant. And of course this isn't thread-safe.

Comment: The thread safe part is  clear I understand that.  But why is this not re-entrant?  Does this just mean that the same thread cannot access this code, meaning don't make it recursive or call it from an ISR?

Comment: I stated it in the first sentence. Re-entrant implies that calling the function with the "same" arguments from "different" threads simultaneously is safe.
For example `int sum(int a, int b) { return a+b; }` is re-entrant.

Comment: And I tried to say that a thread-safe function doesn't mean it is a re-entrant function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-entrant safety means that the function can successfully handle an "out of context" call to itself while it is executing. In non-kernel code in modern operating systems, this usually means that another thread will be calling it at the same time so in this case it is equivalent to being thread-safe.

However, e.g. in MS-DOS or in kernel code, an interrupt could occur at any time while the function is executing, possibly invoking the function on its own; this could have strange side-effects unless the function is written specifically to avoid this.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29

Comment: So, basically don't call that code from an ISR or make it recursive?  I read that wiki link but just want to be 100% clear.

Comment: It totally depends on the environment you're working in. You could e.g. turn off interrupts, avoid calling the function from interrupt handlers, etc.

Comment: OK, that was my thinking.  I will document that it should not be called from an ISR or become recursive.  I would rather not disable the interrupts.  Thanks.